# Reading and writing cell by cell in a CSV with C++

Tags: c++, excel, csv

I am trying to work with CSV, and as far as I've found there is no open source library which allows you to insert a column or row. Instead, I'm trying to write a code that will simulate that by taking the value of each cell and copying it to the cell to the right. In order to do this I am trying to start from the right and moving to the left so as not to destroy data like moving from left to right would do.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE * qFile;
    qFile = fopen ("Testcsv2.csv", "r+");
    int i, j, k;
    char input [80];
    printf("Variables declared\n");
    for(k=1;k<5;k++)
    {
        printf("k loop entered\n");
        for(i=5;i>1;i--)
        {
            printf("i loop entered\n");
            for(j=1;j<i;j++)
            {
                fscanf(qFile, "%2[^,]", input);
                printf("Input is %s\n", input);
            }
            fprintf(qFile, "%s", input);
        }
    }
    fclose (qFile);
    return 0; 
}
```

Each time I try this the fscanf reads A1 over and over instead of reading A1, then B1, C1, etc.

How do I get this to read cell by cell across, then move down a line and do it over again?

Thanks!

EDIT: The input file is simply the first 4x4 set of cells with the data corresponding to their cell.

ie. 
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
A3 B3 C3 D3
A4 B4 C4 D4

Where each is contained in it's own cell.

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, you should use `std::string` as it is safer and more robust than char array.

Comment: Are you really using C++?  This looks like straight C code with a couple of unused C++ includes.

Comment: Your program is looking for ',' in the input.  Where are they in your posted input?

Comment: I need your help.  My debugger is upgrading, so I can't use it at the moment.  Can you use a debugger and step through your code, looking at variables for me?  Please edit your question with the data.  Thanks.

Comment: You can't write out to a file and expect it to insert data if there isn't enough space in the area you are replacing. Standard file I/O just doesn't work that way.

Comment: You guys will have to forgive me. Basically I took a C++ class where the people who actually knew C++ already told me she was a terrible teacher. She only ever taught us printf and such, never cout or anything like that so I am working with what I have hear. Do you understand what I am trying to accomplish with this code? If there is a better way of going about this I am all ears, but the tutorials I saw on CSV weren't much help. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be printing to your input file:

```
    fprintf(qFile, "%s", input);
```

This may be the reason your file gets corrupted.

Also, where do you handle the end of line?
Usually CSV files are formatted with one row per text line.